# Conditional column selection in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to select columns from a DataFrame according to a particular condition. I know it can be done with a loop, but my df is very large so efficiency is crucial. The condition for column selection is having either only non-nan entries or a sequence of only nans followed by a sequence of only non-nan entries.

Here is an example. Consider the following DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame([[1, np.nan, 2, np.nan], [2, np.nan, 5, np.nan], [4, 8, np.nan, 1], [3, 2, np.nan, 2], [3, 2, 5, np.nan]])

   0    1    2    3
0  1  NaN  2.0  NaN
1  2  NaN  5.0  NaN
2  4  8.0  NaN  1.0
3  3  2.0  NaN  2.0
4  3  2.0  5.0  NaN
```

From it, I would like to select only columns 0 and 1. Any advice on how to do this efficiently without looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***logic***

- count the nulls in each column.  if the only nulls are in the beginning, then the number of nulls in the column should be equal the the position of the first valid index.
- get the first valid index
- slice the index by the null count and compare against the first valid indices.  If they are equal, then thats a good column

---

```
cnull = df.isnull().sum()
fvald = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
cols = df.index[cnull] == fvald
df.loc[:, cols]
```

[image]

---

Edited with speed improvements

***old answer***

```
def pir1(df):
    cnull = df.isnull().sum()
    fvald = df.apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)
    cols = df.index[cnull] == fvald
    return df.loc[:, cols]
```

***much faster answer using same logic***

```
def pir2(df):
    nulls = np.isnan(df.values)
    null_count = nulls.sum(0)
    first_valid = nulls.argmin(0)
    null_on_top = null_count == first_valid
    filtered_data = df.values[:, null_on_top]
    filtered_columns = df.columns.values[null_on_top]
    return pd.DataFrame(filtered_data, df.index, filtered_columns)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared. This solution indeed gets the job done, but it takes more than 3 time longer to run than the solution posted below

Comment: @splinter I'm not surprised.  I thought of going the route Nickil took, but I opted for brevity.  Nickil provided a good answer.  I'll update my post though using the same logic, but utilizing a few tricks to speed it up.

Comment: Sounds great @piRSquared

Comment: You are right, it is much faster. In my case it is almost 4 times faster than the solution proposed by NickiMaveli

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `DF` as shown which has `Nans` in various possible locations:

[image]

***1.*** ***Both sides `Nans` present***:

Create a mask by replacing all nans with 0's and finite values with 1's:

```
mask = np.where(np.isnan(df), 0, 1)
```

Take it's corresponding element difference across each column. Next, take modulus of it's values. Logic here is that whenever there are three unique values in each column, then discard that column(namely → -1,1,0) as there would be a break in the sequence for such a situation.

Idea is to take the sum and create a subset wherever the sum results in a value less than 2.(As after taking mod, we get 1,1,0). So, for the extreme case, we get sum as 2 and those columns certainly are disjoint and must be discarded.

```
criteria = pd.DataFrame(mask, columns=df.columns).diff(1).abs().sum().lt(2)
```

Finally transpose the `DF` and use this condition and re-transpose to get the desired result having only `Nans` in one portion and finite values in the other.

```
df.loc[:, criteria]
```

[image]

***2. `Nans` present on top:***

```
mask = np.where(np.isnan(df), 0, 1)
criteria = pd.DataFrame(mask, columns=df.columns).diff(1).ne(-1).any()
df.loc[:, criteria]
```

[image]

Comment: Works great @NickiMaveli, and it does so 3 times fast than the solution above.